# How do you replace a string in a list with two of the same string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Still very much a beginner with python and I am trying to create a function that accepts a list of strings as a parameter and replaces each string with a duplicate of each string. I am having a bit of trouble with the code..

I was able to duplicate each string, but I am having trouble because each word is in one string, and my original list is printing the blist.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

This is what I have so far:

```
blist = []

def double_list(alist):
    for i in alist:
        blist.append(i*2)
    return blist

print('original list: ',double_list(['how','are','you?']))
print('double list: ',blist)
```

Output:

```
original list:  ['howhow', 'areare', 'you?you?']
double list:  ['howhow', 'areare', 'you?you?']
```

EXPECTED Output:

```
original list:  ['how', 'are', 'you?']
double list:  ['how', 'how', 'are', 'are', 'you?', 'you?']
```

Comment: As "original list" you also print the result of the doubling function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `* 2` idiom, you can use `extend()` and pass it a list with two items made with `[i] * 2`.

For example:

```
def double_list(alist):
    blist = []
    for i in alist:
        blist.extend([i]*2)
    return blist

orig = ['how','are','you?']
print('double list: ',double_list(orig))
# double list:  ['how', 'how', 'are', 'are', 'you?', 'you?']
```

Note: the reason you were getting the doubles in `original list:  ['howhow', 'areare', 'you?you?']`  is because you are printing the *return* value of the function which is not the original list.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding strings together. Just append them twice.

```
blist = []

def double_list(alist):
    for i in alist:
        blist.append(i)
        blist.append(i)
    return blist

print('original list: ',double_list(['how','are','you?']))
print('double list: ',blist)
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but this helps understand the solution better.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the **extend() - method**, which allows you to **combine two lists** together.

Also you will have to **change the print statements**, because otherwise you will **only** print out the **"duplicated" version** of the list, not the **original**.

Thus we will **extend "blist"** by a list with **2x the desired string**.

Code should look like:

```
blist = []

def double_list(alist):
   for word in alist: 
      blist.extend([word]*2)
   return blist

original_list = ['how','are','you?']
print('original list: ', original_list)
print('double list: ', double_list(original_list))
```